# TestCase Filter in TFSBuild

Tags: nunit, tfs

I am using `Nunit V2.6.4` and `NunitTestAdapter v2.0` to run `selenium` tests in `visual studio 2015`. We also have a build definition set up to run these tests nightly(on selenium grid)in chrome browser. I want to run a subset of these tests in IE and Firefox, so I added a Nunit  Category “SmokeTest”  attribute to some of the tests.
Created a new build definition and included the following in the TestCaseFilter

```
TestCategory = SmokeTest & TestCategory != Remote.chrome
```

Outcome: All tests are selected. 
It looks like the Testcategory filter is being ignored.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: remove the spaces and see if that helps `TestCategory=SmokeTest&TestCategory!=Remote.chrome` This works for me with Nunit 2.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search gave what is probably the answer:

For NUnit, you need to use Category instead of TestCategory. You may also need to remove spaces - the examples online suggest that your TestCaseFilter should be:

```
Category=SmokeTest&Category!=Remote.chrome
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249366/specify-nunit-categories-with-tfs-vnext-2015

Comment: I used the above mentioned format in the TestcaseFilter , but I got an   Exception Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.TestPlatformFormatException.

Comment: Did you install/configure NUnit correctly - it needs to be installed on your build system, as I recall.